# Avoid trigonometric simplifications?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

When evaluating the expression

```
Sinh[x]^2 + Cosh[x]^2 // FullSimplify
```

I get

```
Cosh[2 x]
```

That is indeed a simplification, but there are cases when I would not want that to happen.

What if I have a much more complicated expression that I want to simplify generally, but still wish to stay in `Sinh[x]^2` and `Cosh[x]^2`. So under no circumstances do I wish to change to `Cosh[2 x]` or similar expressions. Is there a way to explicitly tell Mathematica **not** to use trigonometric relations? Or to use the trivial `Cosh[x]^2 - Sinh[x]^2 = 1` but none of the composed ones?

Preferably, maybe there is a switch that disables the sensitivity of *Mathematica* to trigonometric relations in an entire notebook?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ComplexityFunction` option of `Simplify`/`Fullsimplify` might be of help, for instance

```
FullSimplify[Sinh[x]^2 + Cosh[x]^2, ComplexityFunction -> (Count[{#}, _[2 x]] &)]
```

The idea is to *lead* the simplification process by saying that having expressions with argument `2*x` result to a more complex expression and not a more simplified one. (`Simplify` will try to keep the value of `ComplexityFunction` as low as possible and hence will avoid identities that will increase its value) Of course this example is a crude one because it will count against any occurrence of `2*x` and not only in trigonometric functions. if you know what kind of trigonometric functions are included you can narrow it by giving instead `ComplexityFunction -> (Count[{#}, (Sinh|Cosh|Tanh)[2 x]] &)` or `ComplexityFunction -> (Count[{#}, (Sinh|Cosh|Tanh)[Times[__, x]]] &)` to give a few examples.

Comment: Okay, that sounds nice! And what if I want to avoid any number, not just 2? Like `ComplexityFunction -> (Count[{#}, (Sin|Cos|Tan)[n x]] &)` and `n` being an integer bigger than one? What syntax should I use then?

Comment: Also, is it possible to use a `ComplexityFunction` outside a `FullSimplify`? Like, for all generic computations inside a certain notebook?

Comment: @Kagaratsch something like the last example I gave, `ComplexityFunction -> (Count[{#}, (Sin|Cos|Tan)[Times[Except[1,_Integer], x]]] &)`.

Comment: @Kagaratsch what do you mean by saying outside a `FullSimplify`?

Comment: I noticed, that sometimes even an evaluation which is done without the derictive `FullSimplify` still returns a result which composes two trigonometric functions into a `2 x` one. I would like to avoid that too.

Comment: Only if it is used one of the specialized simplification functions like `TrigReduce`. If you avoid such functions you won't have problem.

Comment: What if my argument in `Cosh[2 x]` is not `x` but is called `y` as in `Cosh[2 y]`, then the ComplexityFunction above will not work any more. Is there a way to assign a placeholder for some variable, instead of using `x` explicitly?

Comment: @Kagaratsch of course you can make the pattern as abstract as you like e.g.  `ComplexityFunction -> (Count[{#}, (Sin|Cos|Tan)[Times[Except[1,_Integer], _]]] &)`

Answer (score 6):

There is also a built in [option switch](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trig.html) that avoids trigonometric simplifications in `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` etc. commands. Use:

```
Simplify[expression, Trig->False]
FullSimplify[expression, Trig->False]
```

to avoid trigonometric relations.