# How to simplify square of a Trigonometric function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have this expression

$a^4 Sin[\phi/2]^4 + 1/2 a^2 b^2 Sin[\phi]^2 + b^4 Cos[\phi/2]^4$.

I expect to get a simple form

$(a^2 Sin[\phi/2]^2 + b^2 Cos[\phi/2]^2)^2$.

However mathematica obtain following expression

```
short1 = FullSimplify[ a^4 Sin[\[Phi]/2]^4 + 1/2 a^2 b^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2 + b^4 Cos[\[Phi]/2]^4]

1/4 (a^2 + b^2 + (-a^2 + b^2) Cos[\[Phi]])^2.
```

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: you can obtain the desired output with `FullSimplify[
  a^4 Sin[\[Phi]/2]^4 + 1/2 a^2 b^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2 + 
     b^4 Cos[\[Phi]/2]^4 /. \[Phi] -> 2 \[Phi] // 
   TrigFactor] /. \[Phi] -> \[Phi]/2`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why we have to transform $\phi/2$ to $\phi$ first?

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23484/avoid-trigonometric-simplifications is useful

Comment: Maybe the Simplify tries to expand Phi/2...Another way without angle replacement is `a^4 Sin[\[Phi]/2]^4 + 1/2 a^2 b^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2 + 
    b^4 Cos[\[Phi]/2]^4 // TrigFactor // Expand // Factor`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = a^4 Sin[\[Phi]/2]^4 + 1/2 a^2 b^2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2 + 
  b^4 Cos[\[Phi]/2]^4;
```

Try this:

```
Factor[expr /. Sin[\[Phi]] -> 2 Sin[\[Phi]/2]*Cos[\[Phi]/2]]

(*  (b^2 Cos[\[Phi]/2]^2 + a^2 Sin[\[Phi]/2]^2)^2   *)
```

Done. Have fun!